# Script-Generated GameObject's Transform properties seem random and impossible to change with just a script. Why and how to fix?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Btw I'm not using a prefab, but it's basically what a prefab does but entirely inside the script.

The code it self is running as expected and doesn't behave unexpectedly. It's just that Transform related changes  seem to be practically skipped over. (Positions, rotations , scale and RectTransform for a UI Text too, which is a GameObject with a 'Text' component and yeah I've tried changing things to the Transform and The RectTransform)

I'm using scripts to generate similar GameObjects instead of me adding them manually, because if I wanted more, the code I wrote wouldn't even change since it would be practically the same case.

For the Game Objects specifically:

```cs
private void Awake()
    {
        GameObject obj= new("obj-1");
        obj.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
        obj.transform.parent = transform;
        obj.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;
        obj.transform.localScale = transform.localScale;
        obj.transform.position = transform.position;


        AddObj(transform);
    }

private void AddObj(Transform Grandparent)// Unrelated and works
    {
        int n = 2;
        foreach (Transform Parent in Grandparent)// Unrelated and works
        {
            foreach (Transform child in Parent)// Unrelated and works
            {
                GameObject obj = new("obj-" + n++);// Works
                obj.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();// Unrelated and works

                // Problematic (?) area I guess
                obj.transform.parent = child;              
                obj.transform.rotation = child.rotation;
                obj.transform.localScale = child.localScale;
                obj.transform.position = child.position;
            }
        }
    }
```

Also for the Texts specifically:

```
public Canvas canvas;
public Transform panel;

private void Start()
    {
        List<string>  props = MCP.GetPropertiesNames();// Not causing issues
        for (int n = 0; n < props.Count; n++)
        {
            GameObject Object = new("Property-" + (n + 1));// Works
            Object.transform.SetParent(panel);// Works

            Object.transform.position = Vector3.zero;// Doesn't Work
            Object.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 0f);// Doesn't Work
            Object.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;// Doesn't Work

            Text text = Object.AddComponent<Text>();// Works
            text.text = props[n];// Works

            text.rectTransform.position = Vector3.zero;// Doesn't Work
            text.rectTransform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 0f);// Doesn't Work
            text.rectTransform.localScale = Vector3.one;// Doesn't Work

            RectTransform rect = text.GetComponent<RectTransform>();// Works

            rect.sizeDelta = new(panel.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.x / props.Count, 50);// Works

            rect.anchorMin = new((n + 0f) / props.Count, 1);// Works
            rect.anchorMax = new((n + 0f) / props.Count, 1);// Works
            rect.pivot = new(0, 1);// Works
        }
    }
```

I've tried using different transform related methods to set values and even tried putting those methods in the Update() method and it still wouldn't change the values properly. It's possible for parent-child positions to have problems with local and world positions, but with my code execution I'm doubtful.

I expected to be able to just change the values and have them stay as expect (you know, what's actually supposed to happen)

Comment: When you say doesn't work, are you looking at the inspector values and not debugging the values?  The inspector shows the local values, this might be where the confusion is.

Comment: I guess? Maybe? Any help for that then?

Comment: What do you need help with?  You can always use `Debug.Log` to check the values you are setting.

Comment: I've tried that and many other options, but the problem here doesn't really seem to be coming from my code since it works. The only part that doesn't work is the transform related changes which are practically negated when the game is ran. As I've said I have no idea what is even preventing me from changing the values or what is actually setting them since the only code with access to those transforms would be the inside the for loops where the objects are created. And for the Debug.Log test, I've got no idea what to even check and if the inspector shows local values as you said then Idk.

Comment: My assumption is that Unity has a problem with how it handles script-generated objects thus the basic physical attributes of the transform being weird. But I'm not confident enough on my skill to blame the Game Engine sooo idk. I just need help to set those values. If you need to replicate the "problem" you could try just generating a game object in a script then running the game, then pausing the game and then just check it's transform in the inspector or just watch where it is. Btw unless you add a texture it'll be invisible.

Comment: There is definitely no problem with the engine in regards to the transform.   For ui elements (that use RectTransform), you probably want to be using `anchoredPosition` and the like.  Can you give an example of one issue where you set the transform property and get unexpected results.  Please state exactly what you set, what you expect, and how it differs.   Please add these details to your question and not as additional comments.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that below the 2 code blocks I've added a decent enough explanation about what I've tried and what I expect to get without an occurrence of the problem. But honestly if that's not enough or something I'd be stumped since that's literally all the info I could give since this problem isn't even related to my code execution and just checking something there wouldn't result in anything useful. Also it's not just positions which are random, the scale and the rotation too, which is why I'm saying that the whole transform is having some problem.

Comment: At this point I'd be fine if someone tried to do what I've tried and see if actually works, because I've got no idea on what to actually do since, as I've said multiple times, the code works fine and it does generate those game objects and adds or changes some values properly too, except in the transform. But I did try to use anchoedPosition3D on the Texts and hey it's where it needs to be now. So, thanks for that. But the game objects from the first code block also STILL have that issue (even though I've been setting their world positions to some other world position).

Comment: And maybe if you can also show me how to properly add a Font to the texts in a script would be helpful too. And just to clarify, since the game objects are script generated that means that they can only be changed in a script since the game would have to be ran for them to start existing.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is what I said earlier regarding local values.  eg. If the parent scale is (5,5,5) and you set local scale on the child to be (1,1,1), its scale is (5,5,5) in world scale and (1,1,1) in local scale.  If you are looking at the values in the inspector, you are seeing the local values (you'd see 1's but the scale is actually 5's).  If you unparent the object(s) in question you will see the world values.

Comment: so it would be a matter of assigning the transform values before settting it's parent? Sure.

Comment: Ok so after fidgeting with values and ideas I managed to make the Texts work by:  1. Creating the GameObject, 2. Adding the 'Text' component then 3. Setting the parent of the GameObject to the panel where I want the text.

Comment: I haven't found anything for the GameObject specific one. But I have figured out that now the only problem they have is the position, but after trying local and world for the parent and the child I haven't managed to find anything.

Comment: Turns out that the y position goes downwards constantly every frame (no idea how though). x and z are I assume good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so for the GameObject the fix is:

```
    GameObject obj = new("obj-" + n++);
    obj.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
    obj.transform.SetParent(child);

    obj.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(child.transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 0f));
    obj.transform.localScale = child.localScale;
    obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false; // Gravity was the problem since 'obj' doesn't have a collider but has a rigid body, which has useGravity set to true by default.
```

For the texts:

```
    GameObject Object = new("Property-" + (n++));// Works
    Text text = Object.AddComponent<Text>();
    Object.transform.SetParent(panel); // Needs to be after "Text text = Object.AddComponent<Text>();" but before assigning rectTransform values.

    text.rectTransform.anchoredPosition3D = Vector3.zero;
    text.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 0f);
    text.rectTransform.localScale = Vector3.one;
```